# adding image through css adds an additional border around image

Tags: html, css

I added the logo for my site in the html before like this:

and that looks great. But now i want different css-files to load different logos.[image]

```
.companylogo {
background-image: url("/Images/Logo.png");
width: 166px;
height: 14px;
border: none;
}
```

but when i do this i get a little border around the images.
[image]
How do i get that little boarder to disappear?

THis might not be the best jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bewsbews/z9kf21fp/ but as you can see the two first images have a little border around them and they were both made with css and the big burgerking logo is made in the html and that doesn't have a border around it.

Comment: can you send me the link? so it will easy to find out the issue

Comment: this seems there is some blankspace in your wiev... can you show your html code or make a fiddle?

Comment: The problem is probably in your `.png` file since the CSS you posted will not generate a border.  You might have some other CSS rules interacting with the `.companylogo` rule, especially if you are using a template based system (CMS, Bootstrap, Wordpress and so on).

Comment: im using bootstrap. But if i style the img-tag with border:none it should overwrite the bootstrap css?

Answer (score 0):

A live demo would be better, i think somewhere in your css is the problem, the code above seems okay.

Comment: added a jsfiddle! Check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

put this in the top of css file

```
img, a {border:0, outline: none;}
```

Comment: sorry, that didn't help! :(

Comment: @DanielGustafsson provide live demo.it will easy to find out the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so it is pretty unnecessary to use an img tag when i don't use the src propertie of the image tag. So i changed it to a div and that solved the problem. Obviously there is no need to have a background-image of an img-tag.